# cntk installation error in Ubuntu 16.04 with cpu only

Tags: python, linux, deep-learning, cntk

In Ubuntu 16.04. I am trying to install cntk (package downloaded from githup- cntk for Linux version and for CPU only).

I followed the procedure written in GitHub. Step 1:

```
anjana@anjana-VirtualBox:~/cntk/Scripts/install/linux$ ./install-cntk.sh
```

I got the following error

```
.Could not connect to https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
..
Solving package specifications: .
Error: Packages missing in current linux-64 channels: 
  - h5py 2.6.0 np111py35_2
  - matplotlib 1.5.3 np111py35_0
  - numpy 1.11.2 py35_0
  - pandas 0.19.1 np111py35_0
  - pillow 3.4.2 py35_0
  - pyyaml 3.12 py35_0
  - scipy 0.18.1 np111py35_0
  - seaborn 0.7.1 py35_0
  - setuptools 27.2.0 py35_0
+ echo Creating Anaconda environment failed.
Creating Anaconda environment failed.
+ rm -rf /home/anjana/anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35
+ exit 1
```

Comment: Which command did you use? Do you have an archive or do you use a package manager?

Comment: I edited the post. Is this an issue with firewall or proxy settings? I don't have archive or package manager.

Comment: Did you try to ping that url? Does it make sense to install as root via sudo?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

This is might be due to proxy issues during the anaconda update after install.  See: http://conda.continuum.narkive.com/crmi1F8C/could-not-connect-to-http-repo-continuum-io-pkgs-pro-linux-64